# Issues with Formula in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a few issues with trying to populate values using relative values not specific.

This works as is, however I need to be able to do a relative cell match. I have tried to change the word Formula1 to FormulaR1C1 and tried to use R2C3 rather than B3, but this does not work.

My thinking is that if I use FormulaR1C1 I can then use R[1].... to specify the cell I need to match to.

x is a row I have already located. at the moment it is row 2, which gives x=2.
categoryColumn and CategoryStart are named ranges defined in the worksheet.
This formula exists to populate a dependent dropdown list, and as said it works as is, but doesn't work how I need it to work.

```
With Cells(x + 1, 3).Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= _
    "=OFFSET(CategoryStart,MATCH(B3,CategoryColumn,0),1,COUNTIF(CategoryColumn,B3),1)"
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have to play with this a little but I think this should work. The idea is to make the formula string dynamic so that it changes as the rows change, correct? Another possible way would be to save the intended formula after concatenation into a string and insert it that way.

```
With Cells(x + 1, 3).Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= _
    "=OFFSET(CategoryStart,MATCH(B" & (x + 1) & ",CategoryColumn,0),1,COUNTIF(CategoryColumn,B" & x+1 & "),1)"
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

Comment: Yes, the line I haven't included looks for a word in column A when it finds that word it inserts a line underneath, that line then needs a few drop downs added. Your code almost worked, I got it to work by changing `....B" & x+ 1 & ",Ca....` to `....B" & (x + 1) & ",Ca....` Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:
Set the String `Formula1R1C1` to be the formula in terms of Rows and Columns e.g.

```
FormulaR1C1="=SUM(R1C1:R4C4)"
```

(just as an example)

then do

```
Formula1:=Application.Evaluate(Application.ConvertFormula(FormulaR1C1, xlR1C1, xlA1))
```

In this way, you can write the formula in terms of **relative** references, then convert it into **absolute** references to be used in your code (which you say does work with absolute references)